# Why do I sometimes get a Type Error "no implicit conversion of StringIO into String" here? Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a line of code in one of my mailers to add an attachment with the surname and DoB of the user. Type Error "no implicit conversion of StringIO into String" sometimes occurs in the `File.read` method.

```
attachments["#{@user.last_name.downcase}-#{@user.date_of_birth.strftime('%d%m%y')}.jpeg"] = File.read(URI.parse(@user.profile_picture_url).open)
```

It works most of the time, but occasionally it just fails with this error. I'm using carrierwave to upload the files to a remote S3 bucket, if that makes a difference.

EDIT:

I've done some digging in the console which has frankly left me more confused! I have two user records, both with profile pictures uploaded via carrierwave to S3. If I just isolate the `File.read` method and try it using both records one works and one doesn't. Inspecting the URI, they appear to be virtually identical.

However, I have found that carrierwave supports a shortcut to read files which solves the problem. Here's the updated code:

```
attachments["#{@user.last_name.downcase}-#{@user.date_of_birth.strftime('%d%m%y')}.jpeg"] = @user.profile_picture.read
```

Comment: Fails with what error?

Comment: @LinFelix edited for clarity. The error is a Type Error, "no implicit conversion of StringIO into String"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything less than `10kb` opens as `StringIO` instead of `File`. Couldn't find an actual reference in the docs, so here is the source:

```rb
StringMax = 10240
def <<(str)
  @io << str
  @size += str.length

  # NOTE: once you pass 10kb mark, you get a tempfile.
  #                      v
  if StringIO === @io && StringMax < @size
    require 'tempfile'
    io = Tempfile.new('open-uri')
    io.binmode
    Meta.init io, @io if Meta === @io
    io << @io.string
    @io = io
  end
end
```

*https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_0/lib/open-uri.rb#L398*

---

Let's test it:

```
>> require "open-uri"

>> File.write("public/small.txt", "a"*10240)
=> 10240
>> URI.open("http://localhost:3000/small.txt").class
=> StringIO

>> File.write("public/large.txt", "a"*(10240+1))
=> 10241
>> URI.open("http://localhost:3000/large.txt").class
=> Tempfile
```

You can `File.read` a `Tempfile`, but you can't `File.read` a `StringIO`.

The fix is to call `read` on the *URI*:

```
>> URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/small.txt").read.class
=> String
>> URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/large.txt").read.class
=> String

# also works
>> URI.open("http://localhost:3000/small.txt").read.class
=> String
```

*https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/openuri/openread#method-i-read*

Comment: Thank you, this is certainly the correct answer. All the files the issue is present on are smaller than 10kb.  This is correct fix for the underlying issue, however I have also found a way to do it using carrierwave's built in read method.